# session in triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

hello
' 
if i create a triggers in mysql now i want to update a table a field when data insertion in table b occurs...then how can i do this for that specific user as i want to know how can i use session_id in triggers or if there is any other way to do this.'

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following trigger will insert a row into table_b for each insert that takes place in table b.
The newly inserted fields of table_a are accessed by the alias `new`.

```
CREATE
  TRIGGER ai_tableb_each AFTER INSERT
  ON table_b FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE vUser_id varchar(255);
  DECLARE vConnection_id integer;    

  SET vUser_id = current_user();
  SET vConnection_id = connection_id();

  INSERT INTO table_b
    (field_a, f_user, f_connection)
    VALUES (
      new.field_a
      , vUser_id
      , vConnection_id
    );
END
```

Note that the declared variables are not really needed, but you may want to do some action depending on the user or connection id.